# left side checkmark and unchecked in table view

Tags: ios5

i tried a lot on checked and unchecked but i am not getting exactly what i want.i written  the programme for that but its not working properly.when i am touching the rows the checkmarks are not coming,if i am pressed 2 times its working,please solve my problem

at  did select row at index i comapared my table image and the check mark image but its not comming

```
if ((cell.m_checkImageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"]))

{
    cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected.png"];
}
else
{
    cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];

 NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
}
  // cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected.png"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am glad posting my answer here. It may be late. But i am sure it will help someone.

Your need to slightly change your code. 
First set accessibilityIdentifier for the subview (Just like you are setting image, set accessibility identifier. Its a string so you can set it same as your image name).

Each time you set image, set accessibility identifier as well.
Next time check accessibility identifier rather than checking image directly.

I am posting a sample code here.

```
        [checkBoxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBoxButton setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"check_box.png"];
```

And while Checking, see below code

```
 if([checkBoxButton.accessibilityIdentifier isEqualToString:@"check_box.png"])
{

    if (chatImageView.image == nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Image" message:@"Please select an image first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        return;
    }

    [checkBoxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBoxButton setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"check_box_selected.png"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chatImageView.image,1);
    NSUserDefaults  *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (profileImageSelected == NO) {
        [userDefault setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"ProfileChanged"];
        [userDefault synchronize];
        [self makeProfileImage:imageData isStatus:@"1"];
        profileImageSelected = YES;
    }
    else{
        [userDefault setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"ProfileChanged"];
        [self makeProfileImage:imageData isStatus:@"0"];
        profileImageSelected = NO;
        [ userDefault synchronize];

    }




}
else{


   [checkBoxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBoxButton setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"check_box.png"];

    [profileImageView setImage:nil];


}
```

Note: My sample code is just to illustrate , how it works.
Hope i am helpful.